# How to anchor buttons to bottom of view when rotated?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, interface-builder

I have a view on an iPad that contains one UIWebView consuming most of the display and two buttons at the bottom. When I rotate left, the buttons end up on the right and I have a gap on the left not filled by the uiwebview.

What I would like is for the buttons to always be on the bottom and for the uiwebview to fill the remaining space. I have tried various options with autosizing in interface builder without success.

Is this possible with autosizing? It seems like a fairly simple scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Set the button's `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin` and the web view's to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`.

Comment: So I tried adding this to the end of viewDidLoad:

 `   continueButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    upgradeButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`

But it seems no different to my attempts to set autosizing in interface builder. In landscape view the buttons are on the right instead of the bottom and the webview leaves a gap on the left.